# how we can add code in infopath button control?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

We have enterprise version of sharepoint server 2010. We have created sharepoint 2010 custom list in sharepoint site. and using infopath with sharepoint list option ("customized forms").After that we added one button control then go to actions and select submit options and when we check submit option it does not show visual studio editor button enabled. Please let me know how i can add custom code in sharepoint list new form in infopath.

Answer (score 1):

Select the button - right click "Button Properties" - click "Edit Form Code"